# Black portion in place of transparent portion while saving the bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am frustrated searching almost every google page for this problem.

I need to save my bitmap to file.
I have used this method several times with no problem at all. But now I am having a problem.

The Bitmap I am saving is a round image with transparency and having .png format which I have placed in res folder. But I am getting black portion in place of transparent portion.

This is the code I am using for saving the bitmap.

```
void saveImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

        finalImg = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "emoticon_temp" + ".png");

        finalImg.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(finalImg);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am saving this bitmap as file because I need to share this image and for sharing the image I need the Stream Uri.

If you got any other Idea for sharing a bitmap, please let me know.

Comment: Are you opening it in the stock Gallery app? Make sure you check it on a computer, it might be transparent but the Gallery apps just display on a black background so it's not obvious what the colour is.

Comment: share a Bitmap vie a custom ContentProvider then

Comment: yeah in gallery its showing black portion but when I am opening it in my computer its not showing black portion. But the main thing thing is that while sharing that image its showing black portion. @f2prateek

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more how a custom content provider will help me in getting rid of the black portion? @pskink

Comment: " i f you got any other Idea for sharing a bitmap, please let me know. " you wanted an idea,  so i gave you that

Comment: how do you decode that image?

Comment: I dont need that image again for decoding. I ust need to share that image. So i am using this code for sharing the image I have saved. Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
     .from((Activity) mContext).setType("image/png")
     .setStream(Uri.fromFile(f)).getIntent()
     .setPackage(WHATSAPP_PACKAGE);
   mContext.startActivity(shareIntent); @pskink